# Trying to remove html from text with Java

Tags: java, html, regex

I've got an `ArrayList<String>` named `fields`. I'm trying to parse the HTML in each `String` using the `replaceAll` function, but I get the feeling that I'm screwing up the regex String (I got the 2nd regex [here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-html-tag-with-regular-expression/) to represent a generic html expression).  Can anyone give me some tips on how to correct myself here?

```
for(int j = 0; j<fields.size(); j++)    
{
    String k = fields.get(j);
    k.replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
    k.replaceAll("<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>", "");
    k.replaceAll("&lt;", "<");
    k.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
    fields.set(j, k);
}
```

Comment: It would be far easier to use something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Then you just need to do `Jsoup.parse(str).text();`

Answer (score 4):

Remember that strings are immutable, so you want to re-assign `k` each time you call `replaceAll`:

```
String k = fields.get(j);
k = k.replaceAll("<br>", "\n");
...
```

Comment: *facepalm*

You're absolutely correct, thanks.  That fixed everything.

Comment: No, it didn't fix everything.  You're still using regular expressions.